# How to test if a variable coefficent is influenced by a dummy variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, categorical-data

I have the following model: salary ~ age + sex

with sex: a dummy variable with male 1 and female 0 and age a continue variable.

I want to transform the model to know  whether the coefficient of age is statically different for the male and the female.

I thought about to fit age in function of salary and sex:

age ~ salary + sex

and after to check if the coefficient sex is significant.

Or an other way: to add a new variable age x sex in the model:

salary ~ age + sex + agesex

and to check if the coefficient of agesex is significant.

Which one is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply add the interaction term and use the model

> salary ~ age + sex + age * sex

If the interaction term is significant, then the slope for males is different from the slope for females.

Comment: ok thanks, the other way is true or not?

Comment: The other way analyses the effect of the salary on age, allowing for different intercepts for male and female. Not really what you are looking for ;)